# Python: subsetting data frame using a list

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I am a newbie to python and I have a very simple question.
I have a **list** of indices which correspond to the some row indices of the data frame. What is the best way to use this list (in the **order** of the items) to subset a data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iloc`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 200, (10, 2)), columns=['a', 'b'])
print(df, end='\n\n')
print(df.iloc[[7, 2, 3, 1, 6]])
```

Output:

```
    a    b
0  144  147
1  164  167
2  167  109
3  183  121
4  136  187
5  170  188
6  188  112
7  158  165
8  139  187
9  146  188

     a    b
7  158  165
2  167  109
3  183  121
1  164  167
6  188  112
```

If you want to use a `list` that corresponds to values in a *column* instead, then we need to *merge*:

```
values = [158, 167, 183, 164, 188]
print(pd.merge(pd.DataFrame([158, 167, 183, 164, 188], columns=['a']), df, on='a', how='left'))
```

Output:

```
     a    b
0  158  165
1  167  109
2  183  121
3  164  167
4  188  112
```

Comment: thank you, very helpful! how can I do a similar subsetting where the list I have corresponds to the elements in the first column instead of the data frame indices?

Comment: @user5054 That would require a fairly different method. Is that in fact your problem?

Comment: Yes, this is my actual problem @gmds . I got the indices of the first column elements using `indices = [data_fr[colname] == g for g in listitems]` thinking I could use what you suggested after this step, and then I realized these were all logicals (and weirdly, all `False`), not indices. I think it would be more efficient to directly index based on the elements in column `colname`.

Answer (score 0):

"how can I do a similar subsetting where the list I have corresponds to the elements in the first column instead of the data frame indices?"

-->

```
[x for x in df['a'] if x in list_of_elements]
```